# Iterating through a list to generate calendars

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iteration, generator, vue.js

I'm iterating through a list to generate calendars, the issue is each generator function has the same `this.addToCalendar()` function. I'd like to know how I could condense this into only being called once, rather than in each function.

The main generators I'd like to look at are the ones within `method`, where I am generating calendar links as well as calling an external api.

CSS has been removed to focus on JS logic.

```
<template>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(calendar, i) in calendars" :key="i">
      <button @click="calendar.generator">
        <span>{{ calendar.type }}</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="setExpanded(false)">
    Close
  </button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  ICalendar,
  GoogleCalendar,
  OutlookCalendar,
  YahooCalendar,
} from 'datebook'
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      calendars: [
        { type: 'Apple', generator: this.generateAppleCalendar },
        { type: 'Google', generator: this.generateGoogleCalendar },
        { type: 'Outlook', generator: this.generateOutlookCalendar },
        { type: 'Yahoo', generator: this.generateYahooCalendar },
      ],
      success: null,
      error: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      event: 'event/event',
      expanded: 'calendar/expanded',
      userType: 'user/userType',
    }),
    eventLocation() {
      return `${this.event.location_street}, ${this.event.location_city}, ${this.event.location_state}. ${this.event.location_zip}`
    },
    generateConfig() {
      const config = {
        title: this.event.title,
        location: this.eventLocation,
        description: this.event.description,
        start: new Date(this.event.start_time),
        end: new Date(this.event.end_time),
      }
      return config
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      setExpanded: 'calendar/setExpanded',
    }),
    generateAppleCalendar() {
      const icalendar = new ICalendar(this.generateConfig)
      icalendar.download()
      this.addToCalendar()
    },
    generateGoogleCalendar() {
      const googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendar(this.generateConfig)
      this.openInNewTab(googleCalendar.render())
      this.addToCalendar()
    },

    generateOutlookCalendar() {
      const outlookCalendar = new OutlookCalendar(this.generateConfig)
      this.openInNewTab(outlookCalendar.render())
      this.addToCalendar()
    },
    generateYahooCalendar() {
      const yahooCalendar = new YahooCalendar(this.generateConfig)
      this.openInNewTab(yahooCalendar.render())
      this.addToCalendar()
    },
    openInNewTab(url) {
      const win = window.open(url, '_blank') // Opening a new tab with the url
      win.focus() // Focussing the users browser to new tab
    },
    async addToCalendar() {
      let url

      if (this.userType === 'guest') {
        url = `event/${this.event.id}/add-guest-user`
      } else {
        url = `event/${this.event.id}/guest`
      }

      const response = await this.$axios.post(url)
      if (response.status === 201) {
        this.success = true
      } else {
        this.error = true
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to answer. Required is... How the calendars relate? How does instantiating a calendar effect the state and thus behavior of `addToCalendar`? Do all calendars require the call? Are you expecting only one valid calendar, some calendars to be successful, or all calendars to set `this.success = true`? What should happen to calendars that result in `this.error = true`? Do you know ahead of instantiating calendars which you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know how I could condense this into only being called once, rather than in each function.

One option would be to make a method that accepted the calendar or type and called the associated method

```
methods:
    generateCalendar(type) {
        const generateMethod = `generate${type}Calendar`
        if (typeof this[generateMethod] === 'function')
          this[generateMethod]()
          this.addToCalendar()
        }
      }
```

Then pass the type:

```
<button @click="generateCalendar(calendar.type)">
```

If the only property being accessed in the loop was that type property then destructuring assignment would allow it to be simplified:

```
 <li v-for="({ type }, i) in calendars" :key="i">
   <button @click="generateCalendar(type)"> 
      <span>{{ calendar.type }}</span>
    </button
```

Alternatively, with using the method above the `generator` properties of the calendars could be removed, and `calendars` could perhaps just be an array of strings.

Also, it seems that three of the four calendar methods are nearly identical other than the class of calendar object created: `generateGoogleCalendar`, `generateOutlookCalendar` and `generateYahooCalendar`. A generic method could be used to replace those three methods (and accept the calendar type as a parameter to be used to dynamically invoke a constructor) or create them dynamically in a loop.